# Live updating data in React-native from Firebase(with NestJs)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working learning React Native/Reactjs with NodeJs(NestJs) and Firebase. I have some problems with updating live data. For example, I have and bell icon which represent Notification and I want it to update whenever the data change and show the number of unread noti in database. My code:

***API***

```
  async getNotifications(data: any): Promise<any> {
    const receiverId = data.userId;
    const warehouseId = await this.getKhoId(receiverId);
    const ref = db.ref('/Notification');
    const result = [];
    await ref.once('value', function (snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.val())
        for (let j = 0; j < warehouseId.length; j++)
          for (let i = 0; i < snapshot.val().length; i++) {
            if (
              snapshot.val()[i] &&
              snapshot.val()[i].warehouseId == warehouseId[j]
            ) {
              result.push({
                content: snapshot.val()[i].content,
                read: snapshot.val()[i].read,
                time: snapshot.val()[i].time,
                number: i,
              });
            }
          }
      else return 'None';
    });

    return result;
  }
```

***React Native***

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleData = async () => {
      const userId = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("userId");
      const numberOfNoti = await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "http://192.168.1.8:5000/getNotifications",
        data: {
          userId: userId,
        },
      }).then(function (response) {
        let val = 0;
        if (response.data) {
          response.data.forEach((item) => {
            if (item.read === 0) {
              val++;
            }
          });
        }
        return val;
      });
      setNumberOfNoti(numberOfNoti);
    };
    handleData();
  }, []);
```

and the component AppBar contain the bell icon:

```
 {numberOfNoti !== 0 ? (
            <Badge size={16} style={{ position: "absolute", top: 5, right: 5 }}>
              {numberOfNoti}
            </Badge>
          ) : (
            void 0
          )}
```

How can I live updating the number in Badge when data in Firebase change? I also have Notification component which contains a list of Notification and updating state of that Notification(from unread to read onPress) and I want to change the Badge number too.

Answer (score 0):

I realize I can call API to update continuously using setInterval and it looks something like this. I don't know whether it's a proper way or not but it run fine.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const handleData = async () => {
        const userId = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("userId");
        const numberOfNoti = await axios({
          method: "post",
          url: "http://192.168.1.2:5000/getNotifications",
          data: {
            userId: userId,
          },
        }).then(function (response) {
          let val = 0;
          if (response.data) {
            response.data.forEach((item) => {
              if (item.read === 0) {
                val++;
              }
            });
          }
          return val;
        });
        setNumberOfNoti(numberOfNoti);
      };
      handleData();
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
```